# Query user details using the getstream.io activity feed client (using React Native)

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

I would like to be able to fetch the user details for a list of users, preferably in a single API call. Is this possible using the JS client (my preference) or via the REST API?

There is a reference to a `listUsers` interface in the [chat documentation](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/query_users/?language=js):

```js
const response = await client.queryUsers({ id: { $in: ['john', 'jack', 'jessie'] } });
```

but this doesn't seem to be available on the activity feed client. In my activity feed app, I am accessing the client using the `<StreamApp.Consumer>` in react native. `client.queryUsers` is not an available method on this context.

It seems that there is also no general query interface on the [rest APIs](https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#user_detail). I can only see an API to fetch a single user details.

Is there a way to query user details for a list of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible at the moment.

However, it's in the backlog to be added.

As you realize, there is a single user read.

On the other hand, react native is a client which shouldn't query users directly. Needed users can be extended on feed/reaction read via enrichment automatically, which is the difference than chat.

Comment: Thanks ferhat! In the react-native example app (https://github.com/GetStream/react-native-example), there is the SearchScreen component that displays a couple of lists of users ("interesting users", etc). These are hard coded in the example, but this reflects the use case I have. I am able to determine this list of users in my app (external to getstream) and then would like to display the users with their profile image, following status, etc. I guess for now I must just load them one-by-one? Is the single user read interface in the js client or must I use the REST api?

Comment: @zakum1 yes, js client has it, `client.user('your-id').get()`